# Setup JetBrains YouTrack to connect to SVN

Tags: svn, teamcity, issue-tracking, youtrack

I realize that TeamCity must be a bridge between YouTrack and SVN, but I need none of the Teamcity functionality. *I just want to issue Youtrack commands via commit comments* like here:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/YTD3/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit

i.e. a commit message

```
test #ld-1 fixed
```

Would mark the issue ld-1 as fixed.

I'm sure I set up youtrack, teamcity and svn correctly, however what I came to realize is that I need to make a build step in TeamCity that will be executed after a commit for it to work (am I correct?). Is there a way to bypass it completely or make the build not do anything, I just can't find a way.

I'm tearing my hair out, guys, please help me out. Again, I only need teamcity to bridge svn to youtrack. What must I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct assuming that TeamCity must be a bridge. In TeamCity you have to create at least one build configuration. It does not have to do anything. After that you need to check TeamCity-SVN connection works fine: just make sure TeamCity lists your commits.

After you are done, setup YouTrack-TeamCity integration. Please also be aware of requirements related to permissions of TeamCity user which integration runs on behalf of. Please find more details here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/JT-8233#comment=27-230640.

Did I answer your question or you're struggling with some other problem?

Comment: TeamCity lists my new changes, not what I committed previously, but that's ok, isn't it? What I'm struggling is is how to make a build, I chose command line and `date` as the command, but if I try to run it it says "Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements." Again, I don't need a build step at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to install TeamCity build agent as well. The good news is that it's free (in your case). After you are done, you have to update Agent Requirements section of build configuration. This does not mean you will have to actually build with TeamCity.