# Mecurial and YouTrack Integration

Tags: youtrack

I am using YouTrack by JetBrains.

Does anyone now I can monitor repositories to track YouTrack issue Id's in commits when using mecurial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please consider the following discussion: [Setup JetBrains YouTrack to connect to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173870/setup-jetbrains-youtrack-to-connect-to-svn/9190486). Please also mind that there's a free version of TeamCity that will suite your needs.