# How can I give a bug tracker access to my Google Developer Respository?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, youtrack

I'm using Google Cloud Platform.  I have a Google App Engine project with its code stored in a git repo in my Google Developer Repository.  I then use YouTrack to track bugs and would like to integrate it with my Google Developer Repository VCS.  I'm able to use git repos with YouTrack, but it requires an Oauth2 Token.

It seems Oauth2 tokens are available for most Google APIs, but I don't know what API should be used by a 3rd party tool wishing to watch for commits.  I assume this is the same problem faced by those wanting to use Jenkins to monitor their Developer Repo and perform testing and deployments accordingly.

How is this normally done?  (ie get Oauth2 token and allow repo access to a 3rd party tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTrack only supports integration with GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket directly, so solving the login issue does not unfortunately make any sense.
A workaround would be to use TeamCity or Upsource as sort of a bridge between YouTrack and your VCS. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9190486/469159. The answer only mentioned TeamCity, since Upsource had not been released at that moment.

Comment: Thanks, @allex.V.  It appears i can add a non "github.com" URL when adding a "github" server, which I took to mean it would accept any git server URL, even though it says "GitHub".   (Click gear icon, VCS Integration, Add Server, see URL field - it allows any URL).  Am i reading too much into this?  Either way, "Development" isn't listed as a Google API: https://console.developers.google.com/ , so Google may make it impossible to access a repo hosted by them?  What Google API allows repo access?  I'd need to grant accordingly...

Comment: It accepts any url since you can host a GitHub Enterprise. I'm not aware of how to make this work on Google API side.